# Can't persist my data with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jta

I'm geting started with Hibernate and try to save some data into my DB from a web app.

My servlet code is here:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();
    ServletContext ctx = super.getServletContext();
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("agricultural-register-server");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.joinTransaction();
        VolumeType vt = new VolumeType(1, "asd");
        Volume v = new Volume("a", "b", "c", 123123, vt, 1);
        em.persist(vt);
        em.persist(v);
        em.flush();
        em.close();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pr.println("Error occured while testing");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is that it gives me the error :

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

I have put in my persistence.xml the option :

> <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

and it creates ok my tables. So i think that my problem is that i need to make my code transactional. but how can i do that?

If i try to do:

```
em.getTransaction(); //....
```

it gives error (i think because i declared my transaction type as "JTA" on my persistence.xml).

So, can anybody help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

---

I solved my problem by doing this:

```
Context ic = new InitialContext();
UserTransaction ut = (UserTransaction)ic.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
ut.begin();
//...transactional code

ut.commit();
```

Help found at this link: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/transactions/transactions6.html

But anyway, some toughts on this will be welcom.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
em.beginTransaction();
```

and at the end you will need to commit or rollback your transaction with help of respected methods.

Comment: It gives me error because I specified on my persistence.xml file JTA transaction-type. (I think that that's the reason for what i cannot use transaction.)